# How to populate select options from a json file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to populate select options from a json file using angularjs?

I would like to know how can i populate the following as part of dropdown

```
todos.products.[DynamicProductName].attributes.Location
```

DynamicProductName since there are so many different product names under todo.products

http://plnkr.co/edit/LMUqxL4ykOGvTsfFTUoN?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select data-ng-model="test"
data-ng-options="product.attributes.location for product in todos.products">
</select>
```

This is pretty longwinded. It may be better to put a `products` array on the scope and ng-options over that.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOptions` as well as `ngRepeat` both support iterating over collections as well as objects, which is important for your data.  Those `DynamicProductName` values are really just keys within the `products` object.

The basic syntax for using `ngOptions` in this situation is:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in data"></select>
```

In this case, `key` would be what would be stored in your model while `value` would be displayed within the select.

Your value is slightly more nested and thus would be: `value.attributes.location`.

If you would prefer to have the value (possibly more relevant data), then you could change the code to:

```
<select 
    data-ng-model="test" 
    data-ng-options="value as value.attributes.location for (key , value) in todos.products"
    >
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Really helpful